# Power BI Reporting cost optimization

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, azure-analysis-services

We have a reporting solution wherein we transfer data from multiple databases to a single Azure SQL database, which is migrated to Azure analytical services, that are then used to generate the Power BI reports. These reports are embedded into a web application using Power BI Embedded.

Given the license cost of analytical services and power bi Embedded licenses, the overall cost of the solution comes to USD 2500, for the configuration below.

Azure App Service - B1 - USD 55
Azure SQL Database - S3 - USD 172
Azure Active Directory - Basic - USD 1.5 for single user
Azure Data Factory - USD 150
Power BI Embedded - A1 - USD 700
Azure Analysis Services - B2 - USD 600

As you may see, this is the cost when I have used only the first pricing tiers for my solution. The count of my customers will be in single digit for the foreseeable future, the cost per user is currently quite steep.

I am looking for references and suggestions that can help bring down my solution's overall cost. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is not a lot that you can cut out, you could try to bring down the cost by pausing the Power BI embedded, if is not needed 24/7. Again for the Database, can you ramp that down and up? For Azure AD, if i'm right in thinking, you don't need a AD user for each user on your service. My companies PBI Embedded service, handles all the user stuff without AD